# Changing the x value of a horizontal line to be based off a particular time in pinescript version 4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
study("Open Ray to right", overlay=true)
higherTF1 = input("D", type=input.resolution)

dailyopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF1, open)

line1 = line.new(x1=bar_index-1, y1=dailyopen, x2=bar_index, y2=dailyopen, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51), width = 2)

line.delete(line1[1])
```

So I am 100% new to pinescript but I have this peice of code that I have been using for a relatively long time. now wanting to modify it so that the lines x value always starts at the time of the daily open price. the code is on version 4 because again, I have been using it for a long long time - this is an example of what it is doing now[image]

I would much appreciate any help with this. thank you!